# IIS7 Web.Config Caching - what are the differences here, and how does it all come together?

Tags: caching, iis-7, web-config, asp.net-4.0

In IIS7 I've got the ability to set caching options. These options are added to my web.config as such...

```
    <caching maxCacheSize="262144">
        <profiles>
            <add extension=".png" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:00:30" />
            <add extension=".jpeg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:00:30" />
            <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:00:30" />
            <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:00:30" />
            <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:00:30" />
        </profiles>
    </caching>
```

However, I've also got the following for "caching"

```
    <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="90.00:00:00" />
        <remove fileExtension=".js" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript" />
    </staticContent>
```

What are the differences between these two configs?  They are both nested in the `<system.webServer>` tag, so they're both valid for IIS7.

Also, what is the right approach when using these? I currently only use this is my static assets folder. I don't use this caching on anything else.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Chase, were you able to find out anymore information on this? StaticContent seems to be mucking with my caching profiles and I'm curious about any information that could be shared.

Comment: After I asked, I sorta forgot about it. I would like a good canonical answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that

- the first is for server-side caching of dynamic output such as aspx pages (basically keeps the page output in memory for subsequent requests). As @artem-vertiy's answer points out, using it for static content makes no sense.
- the second one is 'internet-side' : it is implemented by writing standard response headers, it tells both client browsers and public proxies how to manage cached files.

Comment: If you specify location="ServerAndClient" in the add extension=".png" tag, you can cache on the client as well as the server

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that people often confuse the things above and write articles where recommend things as in the first block, i.e. output caching for static resources

[Output caching](https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/caching):

> Output caching is **unnecessary for static files, such as HTML, JPG**, or
>   GIF files, and can cause more memory overhead for dynamic ASP.NET or
>   PHP pages that read from a database that changes frequently

Thus

```
<add extension=".png" ../>
<add extension=".jpeg" ../>
etc.
```

is useless at least when you don't have ashx http handler for .png or .jpeg etc.